# Value is not persisted when setting Umbraco True/False property programatically

Tags: c#, umbraco

i'm having trouble with the Umbraco using Umbraco Identity. Trying to set a custom TrueFalse property, the value won't be stored. I have observed that if I set the value through the CMS, the value is reported as either "1" for true, or "0" for false. But when I try to set the value programatically, the value is not saved.

Can someone see what I'm doing wrong?

```
var member = UserManager.FindByEmail(model.Email);

if (model.MarketingOptin) //Always true in this case
{
        member.MemberProperties.First(p => p.Alias == "marketingOptIn").Value = "1";
}
else
{
        member.MemberProperties.First(p => p.Alias == "marketingOptIn").Value = "0";
}
UserManager.Update(member);
```

Comment: It might sound stupid, but could you try doing it through the MemberService? Just to see if that works.

You can do it like this, if you're in a SurfaceController:
            var ms = Services.MemberService;
            var myMember = ms.GetByEmail("test@test.com");
            myMember.SetValue("marketingOptIn", "1"); or try "true" instead of 1, if 1 isn't working.

Comment: @Mikkel your comment should probably be fully fledged answer. It seems to be the correct thing for OP to do.

Comment: @Harvey - thanks. I'll post an answer, then we'll see if OP wants to mark it as one :)

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
var ms = Services.MemberService; 
var myMember = ms.GetByEmail("test@test.com");
myMember.SetValue("marketingOptIn", "1");
```

Or try "true" instead of 1, if 1 isn't working.